# Duplicate entry on loop an ArrayCollection (One To Many Entity)

Tags: php, symfony, exception, doctrine, arraycollection

I have a collection of tags, and every tag has a collection of mappings (one to many relation). The problem is that when I try to loop this collection of mappings, and then I flush my Entity Manager, a duplicate of all the tags are created, and I don´t understand why.

Here is the code with a batch Size. The first foreach loops the tag collection, and then I get all the mappings of this tag. Then, wenn I flush on the foreach I get an exception but if I flush only one time at the end (after the for), it works. Can you please help me?

Here is the exception:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO tag (name) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params ["Test 1"]:
>     SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'Test 1' for key 'UNIQ_C09225D35E237E06'

Here the code:

```
            $batchSize = 100; //Entity Manager will flush every batchSize times
            $i = 0;

            foreach ($aTagCollection as $oTag) {
                $aMapping = $oTag->getMapping();

                foreach ($aMapping as $oMapping) {   

                }

                if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {
                    $this->em->flush(); //Execute all updates every 100 times
                    $this->em->clear(); //Detaches all objects from Doctrine
                }

                $i++;
            }

            $this->em->flush();
```

The entity Tag

```
   /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Mapping", 
        mappedBy="customerLabel", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY", 
        cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
    */
    private $mapping;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->mapping = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    public function addMapping(Mapping $mapping)
    {
        $this->mapping[] = $mapping;

        return $this;
    }


    public function removeMapping(Mapping $mapping)
    {
        $this->mapping->removeElement($mapping);
    }


    public function getMapping()
    {
        return $this->mapping;
    }
```

And the entity Mapping:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="mapping", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
  private $tag;

  public function setTag(Tag $tag = null)
    {
        $this->tag= $tag;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTag()
    {
        return $this->tag;
    }
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't see any persist() in your code just flush()

Comment: Therefore I don´t understand why is created a duplicated of all the tags...  I have only a flush and two foreachs, nothing more

Answer (score 0):

customerLabel ?

```
/** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Mapping", 
    mappedBy="tag", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY", 
    cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
*/
```